Is there anyway to add multiple SaveChangesInterceptor
I already have a SaveChangesInterceptor which is responsible for updating Audit Properties like Created date, CreatedBy, LastModified and LastModifiedBy.
here is the Auditable Code snippet:
public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    UpdateEntities(eventData.Context);

    return base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);
}

public void UpdateEntities(DbContext? context)
{
    if (context == null) return;

    foreach (var entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseAuditableEntity>())
    {
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            entry.Entity.Created = _dateTime.Now;
            entry.Entity.CreatedBy = _currentUserService.UserId;
        }

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Added || entry.State == EntityState.Modified || entry.HasChangedOwnedEntities())
        {
            entry.Entity.LastModified = _dateTime.Now;
            entry.Entity.LastModifiedBy = _currentUserService.UserId;
        }
    }
}

I want to add another SaveChangesInterceptor which will be responsible to convert hard delete to soft delete by setting IsDeleted Property to true
here is the soft delete Code snippet:
public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    SoftDeleteEntities(eventData.Context);

    return base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);
}
public void SoftDeleteEntities(DbContext? context)
{
    if (context == null) return;

    var deletedEntries = context.ChangeTracker
                               .Entries<BaseAuditableSoftDeletableEntity>()
                               .Where(entry => entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
                               .ToList();

    foreach (var entry in deletedEntries)
    {
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        entry.Entity.IsDeleted = true;
    }
}

and here is the dependency injection
services.AddScoped<AuditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor>();
services.AddScoped<SoftDeletableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor>();

the execution enters the Auditable Interceptor but not goes through Soft Delete Interceptor

I thought that right way for registering interceptors is to call AddInterceptor during options configuration as shown in MS examples

Thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv I forgot to pass the Interceptor to AddInterceptor

I registered the Interceptor to DbContext according to @Svyatoslav comment and it works, the code will be like the following
private readonly AuditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor _auditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor;
private readonly SoftDeletableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor _softDeletableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor;

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
   optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(_auditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor);
   optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(_softDeletableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor);
}


AddInterceptors can register two intecptors in one call.
